# Microsoft SQL group by to get multidimensional array

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays

I'm using PHP and Microsoft SQL 2003.

I have this table:

```
Page | Group
------------
   1 |    1
   2 |    2
   3 |    1
   4 |    2
```

I need to get an array grouped by "Group":

```
Array( 
  1 => Array(1, 3), 
  2 => Array(2, 4)
);
```

I am using PDO, I'd like to get the array directly from SQL instead of parse the entire result with a PHP loop.

How can I do?

Comment: this is the full array, and the key to generate the groups is obviously "group"

Comment: @JoeFletch It is pretty clear from the question and the returned data what the OP is trying to achieve. As far as returning an array from an SQL statement goes, you cannot do this unless you use a stored procedure...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I missed it! I will remove my comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return multidimensional array from an SQL statement. You can of course use stored procedures to return multiple recordsets but returning multidimensional arrays is not possible.

I therefore suggest something like the following solution (not tested):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Page,Group FROM SOME_TABLE");

$array = array();
if($stmt->execute()) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $array[$row['Group']][] = $row['Page'];
    }
}
```

This will group the page numbers into their separate groups, and therefore return an array like:

```
Array( 
  1 => Array(1, 3), 
  2 => Array(2, 4)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it not possible in any SQL engine or just on Microsoft SQL?

Comment: It is not possible in any SQL engine as you cannot return an array! You could return a comma separated list, but to do even this you would need a view or a stored procedure. You **cannot** pass an array from SQL to PHP, they are different languages for a start...

Comment: Thank you, so looks like I'll use your snippet.

Comment: @FezVrasta See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: AAHH!! I knew there was a way! Damn Microsoft! Thanks

Comment: @FezVrasta Please be aware that this will not return an array! It will return a comma separated list. You can then use `explode` in PHP to create an array from it. You would still be better off using the solution I have suggested as it is cleaner and much less complicated, therefore easier to maintain :-)

Comment: Get almost all the work done by SQL instead by PHP I think is easy and has best performances.